# Why I can not override WebView 'copy:' method?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, webview

I want to override some WebView's editing action methods. So, I created MyWebView, which is a WebView subclass and redefined the following methods

```
- (void)copy:(id)sender;
- (void)cut:(id)sender;
```

Those methods are listed in the public WebView API, i.e. "copy:"
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WebView/copy:

Sadly, my redefined methods are never called. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the first responder is other class than you have overridden. However, the class you would want to subclass can't be used (link it to WebView).

In this case documentView (WebView->-WebFrame->WebFrameView->documentView) is the first responder and it's implementation is (check macro [here][1]):

```
#define FORWARD(name) \
    - (void)name:(id)sender { [self _performResponderOperation:_cmd with:sender]; }
```

This code calls private method so this is a dead end.

I think you should try to inject javascript that will detect copy and call responsible Obj-C method. Second solution could be overriding NSApplication and check all events that are sent and grab that one you need (unverified + performance degradation).

[1][ http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/WebKit/WebKit-7537.74.9/mac/WebView/WebView.mm ]